# Laravel: Should it be this slow?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get my laravel application to run a bit faster. I currently host 4 websites on the same application, but it seems to be etreemly slow. It usually takes 4-5 seconds to reload a page, I am trying to get than down to about 800ms maximum, is this possible? Should Laravel be this slow?

I am using Debugbar by Barry and I have the following results:

```
Booting (1.38s)
Application (952.49ms)
```

My website URL is http://worldrp.uk if anyone could help? I am just looking for the cause of why its slow, or some way I can find out? all I have right now is the times of booting and application. I currently use XAMPP on a Windows Machine (my own) as I am just developing for myself right now.

Comment: "So there's this movie, and in it there's this guy who does stuff. Know the one I'm talking about?" Can you please be more specific here? The most common reason for slow pages is making way too many, or too demanding database calls. You'll have to look into your logs more deeply. You may also have to disable chunks of your page to see if you can narrow down the origin of the slowness.

Comment: It isn't to do with database calls (I don't think so anyway), I run 1 database call that takes 17.5 milleseconds.

Comment: Are you using route and config caching? `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan config:cache`? Both of those should save a lot of IO and route processing. I believe XAMPP also comes with XDEBUG by default which can bring a lot of slowdown itself.

Comment: If you're using version control (which you should be) just start throwing things overboard, deleting or disabling code, until your page runs more quickly. Then when it does, start putting things back until you find the source of the slowdown. This simple technique is often surprisingly effective.

Comment: I have added all the suggestions here, caching routing and config, taking it out of debug mode, and more but I still don't see much change in the boot time, or the application time.

Comment: Taking it out of debug mode had some performance enhancements but its still relatively slow, above 1 second page load.

Comment: Without being able to see the code, it's hard for anyone to say.  One thing you could try, it to throw a `die('asdf')` into the application at various layers in the MVC and see which one takes the longest.  Start at the top of the lifecycle, maybe in the controller that is responsible for handling the main page's request, then from there go to the model, and the view?

Comment: It seems to be this part of code. $response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

Comment: `Booting (1.38s)` is definitely excessive if you haven't been doing crazy stuff. Have you tried it off the XAMPP install?

Comment: @JoshHallow Found a solution? I've stumbled on your same issue. `capture();` is _extremely_ slow. 6 seconds of boot time.

Answer (score 0):

> Use redis as cache driver , it might help you

Edit app/config/cache.php and change the driver to 'redis'.

'driver' => 'redis',

Also  edit the redis section of app/config/database.php

```
'redis' => array(
    'cluster' => false,
    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),
```

To use the redis cache driver make sure Redis is installed first.

Comment: That's not going to do much with the abnormally high "Booting (1.38s)" value.